# How to replace á character with empty string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am parsing CSV file, there I encounter special characters like `á`.

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

Can any one help me to remove `á` and corrupted characters from the string line.
I tried the following

```
line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
```

but it replacing `:`, `/` `[` `]` symbols.

```
 inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Line : " + line.trim());
     String[] fields = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
     for (int i = fields.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         System.out.println(i + " " + fields[i].replaceAll("[á]", ""));
     }
```

Comment: what do you mean "special characters"? You need to list out all special characters in order to replace it at all. I think no easy way to do so.

Comment: did you try writing and testing a regex in the input before using it in the program?

Comment: Show your input string. And what do you mean by "corrupted"? In normalized Unicode a diacritical is represented in its own code point separate from the code point of the character it modifies. For historical reasons, Unicode adopted a few dozen characters in code points from 128 to 255 ([Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement)) that combine a character plus diacritical into a single code point. The `a` with acute accent is one of those, at 225. These two different ways to represent that character+diacritical may be your issue (just a guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just replace a positive character class containing the accented character(s):

```
String input = "hablá";
input = input.replaceAll("[á]", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

Or

```
input = input.replaceAll("[\\u00e1]", "");
```

**Output:**

```
habl
```

## Demo

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I tried this but not working

Comment: @Krishna I'm surprised that didn't work.  You can also try replacing using the Unicode character sequence for accented letters.

Comment: Hi Tim when I try with input= input.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""); It works

Answer (score 0):

Add the characters you don't want stripped out to your regex pattern match.

e.g.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9$\/\]\[\:\,]+
```

Will match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, /, \, ], [, :, ,, Don't forget to escape special characters in the pattern with a \

Also you can use https://regex101.com/ to check the validity of any regex you create.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method as shown below:

```
line = line.replace("á","");
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WOJE93801)

Comment: Tried this but still its printing aids:áassessment, Thank You

Comment: It is working fine, note that you need to store it back in the line variable again.

Comment: use replaceAll method to replace all characters 'replaceAll("á","")'

Comment: Please try the link for the program, replace method works, here is the link : http://rextester.com/WOJE93801